# Google Analytics reports wrong goal completions and events count

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, goal-tracking

I have this GA-tracked application that is not counting all my events and goal conversions. Events are correctly displayed in the Real-Time chart, but the reports apparently discard some of them. My goal completion counts are being incorrectly reported, too - for example, in a given day my user registration goal displayed less than 20 goal completions but I had almost 100 new users.
I am using Universal Analytics and my pageview count is still low compared to the GA threshold.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I also found few bugs and especially some events not firing properly. Hence, I move to old code again. Even in old code,” doubleclick.js” code  not working for some  Event Tracking. After I replace the code with old” ga.js” file all the event functions start to work without any modifications to the source code. Please stick with the old code for next few months.

Just check Avinash website (http://www.kaushik.net) , as we all know he is the digital marketing evangelist for Google. He is still using the old ga.js code. This tells that this new Universal Analytics code have some hidden bugs and they are testing the code with user experience. Hence this is not the time to fully depend on Universal Analytics. Sooner they will come up with updates and then it will be ok to move to Universal Analytics.